# Merging data frame different rows and different columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

df1

```
  a       b       c

  10      11    10
  00021   11    00021
  022     1     00021
  00054   32    00054
```

and another one like this

df1

```
  name     n

  10       1
  00021    2
  022      1
  00054    1
```

that counts how many times the variables in the column `c` of `df1` appear. I would like to add to the first data frame one column like `n` in `df2`; I tried to merge the two data frame but without success..

Comment: Both data frames are named `df1`? And have you looked at `merge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "c", by.y = "name")

      c     a  b n
1 00021 00021 11 2
2 00021   022  1 2
3 00054 00054 32 1
4    10    10 11 1
```